# Run Chrome or IE with selenium grid2

Tags: c#, selenium-grid

```
DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.Chrome();

IWebDriver wd = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), capability);
wd.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://localhost/");
```

but I always get error

> cannot find : {platform=WINDOWS, javascriptEnabled=true,
>   browserName=chrome, version=}

The same with IE. Only FF works. I search in google and here in forum but none solution works.

http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/GettingStarted

http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver

I am using windows 7 64 bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To run tests on googlechrome using Grid 2.0-Webdriver combination you must use [ChromeDriver](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver). After copying/installing chrome driver in your machine, you need to start RC node with parameter  webdriver.chrome.driver

```
java -jar selenium-server.jar -role wd -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register  -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=path-to-chromedriver
```

For IE you need to start the node like

```
java -jar selenium-server.jar -role wd -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register -browser browserName="internet explorer",platform=WINDOWS ensureCleanSession=true
```

Comment: what about Safari, Android, IPhone, etc? Is there a list of the different commands for these anywhere?

Comment: @Tyler You can check the corresponding wiki article in https://code.google.com/p/selenium/w/list